# Alternating row colors in invoices and purchase orders?

Tags: quickbooks

Multi-line descriptions for templates in Quickbooks (e.g. invoices, packing lists, purchase orders) tend to "muddle together", despite my efforts to add clarity with makeshift bullet points:

[image: Multi-line descriptions in QuickBooks]

I'm able to change the background color of the entire column, but is there any way to make the background color of items (rows) alternate in custom templates?

Comment: What have you done or tried so far? Have you check the Quickbooks Support web site for information **[how to customize your forms](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/pages/inproducthelp/Core/QB2K12/ContentPackage/Core/Customize_Forms/nf_stylesetup.html?family=pro)**?

Comment: @CharlieRB I have become quite familiar with the layout designer in QuickBooks; I'm able to adjust fonts, add borders, and move things around. But alas, if I add a background color to anything, the entire element gets the same color.

Comment: I'm hoping there is some hidden menu that I missed, or at least some answer like _This is possible if you export the template and edit it in a text editor._

Answer (score -2):

Hi If you are using Excel 2013, Go to File menu -> New. In the search box type **Sales invoice tracker1**. You will see a template with alternating coloured rows as you want. There are lots of other templates online - Take your time and select the best one that suits your requirement

Comment: I'm using QuickBooks, actually. I put it in the tags, but I guess I forgot to actually mention that in the answer.